# Have a radio button as a check for base value

Tags: jquery

I've worked through my code, and I've ended up having 2 possible base prices. **Students base = $249.99 and Assistants = $399.99.**

Each option has the choice to add:

a chair $99.99 and/or a desk $99.99.

As of right now my code does not recognize the assistants option($399.99), nor will it do the proper math. All in all: if the assistants option is selected, its supposed to be replaced as the new base price.

**How do I get the base price to switch between the 2 choices and recognize the checkbox values?**

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SNFy/12/) to better display what I'm working with.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
// check if assistant or student
$('input[name=type]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('value') == 1) {
        // if assistant
        var originalAmount = 399.99;
        $('span.amount').html(originalAmount);
    }else {
        // else student
        var originalAmount = 249.99;
        $('span.amount').html(originalAmount);
    }
});
// check the current amount
originalAmount = Number($('span.amount').html().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    sum = originalAmount;
    var names = $(':checked').map(function(){
        sum += (this.value - 0);
        return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
    $('span.amount').text('$' + sum);
    spans[1].innerHTML = sum;
});
```

Comment: Notice the type; `$('span.amount').html(OriginalAmount);` (`originalAmount`). Also `spans[1].innerHTML = sum;` (`spans`) does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I caught that last second. but that isn't the solution.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3SNFy/18/

Basically, change OriginalAmount to originalAmount in

```
$('span.amount').html(originalAmount);
```

Also, you'd want to declare that variable at a global level for the maths to work right.

**EDIT:**
Updated fiddle to account for radio button change along with selection of checkboxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/3SNFy/19/

Comment: Awesome. However, when changing of the base price the checkboxes values aren't considered. They're checked but the price is deducted. How would I go about fixing that?